# How do I read browser version details from a Service Worker?

Tags: javascript, service-worker

From within a Service Worker, Is it possible for me to access browser details such as browser name, version, etc?  I typically use the `window` object from pages to do this, but `window` is not available in the Service Worker's global scipe.

Comment: Have you checked what the this keyword refers to within the service worker & can you not just post a message from the main page, to the service worker with all the details of the browser?